# flex ant compile css

Tags: css, apache-flex, ant

I have a flex project that I need to build with ant. So far I have this

```
<mxmlc file="${flex.src.dir}/MyFlexApp.mxml"
           output="${flex.build.dir}/MyFlexApp.swf"
           services="${conf.dir}/flex/services-config.xml" 
           locale="es_ES,en_US"
           context-root="/${ant.project.name}"
           allow-source-path-overlap="true"
           keep-generated-actionscript="false">

        <load-config filename="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/flex-config.xml"/>
        <source-path path-element="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks"/>
        <source-path path-element="${flex.src.dir}/locales/{locale}" />

        <compiler.include-libraries dir="${flex.lib.dir}" append="true">
            <include name="*.swc" />
        </compiler.include-libraries>
    </mxmlc>
```

In this project I have two .css (Dark.css and Light.css) which are style sheets for custom theme approach and to accomplish with that feature I added compiler options as follow

```
<buildCSSFiles>
<buildCSSFileEntry destPath="bin-debug" sourcePath="flex_src/assets/themes/Dark/Theme.css"/>
<buildCSSFileEntry destPath="bin-debug" sourcePath="flex_src/assets/themes/Light/Theme.css"/>
```

So, what I need is to instruct the build.xml file to also add this compile options. Can anybody help me with this, please? Any advice would be greatfully appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same as compiling a swf just point mxmlc at the css file.

```
<mxmlc file="path/to/css/file/your-css.css"
output="bin-debug/your-css.swf" >
<load-config filename="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/flex-config.xml"/>
</mxmlc>
```